# Will my Xbox One still work if I unplug the HDMI cable?

Tags: xbox-one

I need the HDMI cable for other uses but I'm currently downloading something. If I unplug it will it stop the download?

Comment: Why would it?  HDMI is an audio and video cable; it has nothing to do with your network.

Comment: @Frank actually, this is not a silly question. The OP might expect the xbox detected a missing cable, gave an error, and halted whatever it was doing. This is not the case, but this is why he asked the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually able to turn the Xbox One off. If you hold down the home button, and choose turn off console, as long as the white light on the power box is on, so is your Xbox. Downloads will continue.

Comment: This is only if you have the "instant-on" option enabled.

Comment: Instant-on is on by default though, right?

Comment: @CrabtasticGoat but if it can be turned off, then it should be mentioned in this answer.

Comment: Could you please add that in order to boot the console back up, a HDMI cable needs to be present. Without a cable the console will not boot correctly.

Comment: @Eric, definetly will not boot? HDMI is no longer a requirement to even play the Xboc One (atleast, at the technical level), as you can stream picture to Windows 10.

Answer (score 7):

Removing your HDMi cable does not affect the download at all. I don't even think the Xbox knows that the cable is being unplugged.

So unplugging your HDMI cable is safe. The same goes for any cable other than the internet cable or power cable.

Comment: The Xbox won't go through proper start-up without a video connection, otherwise it's okay to have it unplugged, unless this is only for me....

Comment: the xbox could detect it, as the HDMI lanes include also some for data transfer that is used for i.e medium exchange, so it would at least be possible.

Comment: I don't know about Xbox One, but Xbox 360 can tell when the TV that it's connected to is on the right viewing setting, and actually won't load after you turn it on until it is. This isn't relevant to downloads, but it is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

The HDMI cable is merely an output to an external display which a console without an inbuilt display needs to display content.

In other words, YOU need it to see what the Xbox is doing, but the Xbox has no need of it. So if you remove the HDMI cable, the Xbox will simply stop displaying, which is not necessary to continue downloads.

As long as your internet connection is solid and you have uninterrupted power, you're golden.

Comment: "but the Xbox has no need of it". I don't know about the One, but the 360 will only boot if the cable is connected.